# How can I get the Vault secret by using AppRole with Terraform

Tags: terraform, vault

Can we get the Vault KV values by using **AppRole** with **Terraform** if so please advice what are the policies/documents should I have to be refer.

I found below articles and it stated to have Chef, do we really have this Chef to get the Vault secret? or we can get the Vault secret by using Terraform alone.

https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/approle-trusted-entities?in=vault/auth-methods
https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/auth/approle

Please share you thoughts!

Comment: The Hashi tutorial on approle pull method with Vault and Terraform does not state you have to use Chef. It states that you need a third persona, and it uses Chef as an example of that persona. You can either use Terraform and Vault with the push approle method, or add a third persona (e.g. a pipeline tool) with the pull method. It is your choice.

Comment: ok thanks @matt-schuchard